# How to create SQL Server user define-function using python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to create a simple user-defined SQL Server function using `pyodbc` but the function is not created on the database. If I execute the same query within SQL Server then it is created.

```py
import pyodbc

sql = """
CREATE FUNCTION east_or_west (
    @long DECIMAL(9,6)
)
RETURNS CHAR(4) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value CHAR(4);
    SET @return_value = 'same';
    IF (@long > 0.00) SET @return_value = 'east';
    IF (@long < 0.00) SET @return_value = 'west';
    
    RETURN @return_value
END;
"""

con = pyodbc.connect('Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;Server='+server+';Database='+dbname+';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: I think perhaps you need to call `con.commit()` at the end for your changes to take effect?

Answer (score -2):

Do you need create

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable AS
SELECT customername, contactname
FROM customers;

CREATE TABLE TestTable AS
SELECT customername, contactname
FROM customers;
```

Comment: How does this related to the question asked? No tables are referenced in the question. And your answer is not valid T-SQL?